# how to trigger msbuild script after checking in?

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment

I have a msbuild script that works(build and deployment to another server) from the commandline . I am using vs.net 2012 and tried using the build definition to trigger a similar build by using the exact same msbuild arguments I cant get this to work. Is there another way to trigger this script after checking in?
This is how I call it in the commandline:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe 
C:\dev\buildtestkut\mysol.sln 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:PublishProfile=local.pubxml
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true
/p:UserName=myuser
/p:Password=pw
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on TFS and have a Build Definition, then you'll want to take a look at the "Triggers" tab on the build definition.

In VS2012, in the Team tab, click on the Home icon.  Click on **Builds**, then right click on the Build Definition you wish to edit and click **Edit Build Definition**.  Under the Triggers tab, select Continuous Integration.  This will cause the build to trigger upon each check in.

You can also choose a Gated Check-in, which will cause the build to launch on an attempted check-in, but only commit the changes if the build was successful.

Is your MsBuild script an MsBuild project file or VS .sln file, or by "script" are you referring to a powershell or batch script that invokes msbuild.exe?  If that's the case, then you may want to list the logical steps in your scripts and 'port' that to an MsBuild file that can be launched by MsBuild.exe from the TFS build agent.  (In the Build Definition, click on the **Process** tab, under **Required** -> **Items To Build** -> **Projects to Build**, you can specify one or more projects that can be built using msbuild.exe.)

Comment: @user603007 Once you've added the solution go the "3. Advanced" settings in the Process tab and add your msbuild arguments to the "MSBuild Arguments"